# Install robo3t on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS issue

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I've tried to install robo3t in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I run command *./robo3t*, I received an error:

```
./robo3t: error while loading shared libraries: /home/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/../lib/libQt5Network.so.5: file too short
```

Please help me resolve this issue! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

vist https://askubuntu.com/questions/386281/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libglu-so-1
below command in my aws ubuntu 16.04 instance solved for me
`sudo apt-get install libglu1`